# observeAsState() not surviving navigating between apps - with "Don't keep activities" on

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am experimenting with Jetpack Compose. I'm used to set the Developer Option `Don't keep Activities` to test whether my app still shows data after leaving and entering the app. Currently i have composable function which shows an image retrieved from a piece of LiveData in the view model. Via the following code in the Composable i retrieve this image

```
@Composable
fun MovieDetailScreen(viewModel: MoviesViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val selectedMovie by viewModel.selectedMovie.observeAsState()
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(260.dp)
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(selectedMovie?.getBackdropUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_movie_24)
                .crossfade(true)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .build(),

            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.app_name),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
    }
}
```

Basically when I navigate to another app and then navigate back the image is gone. `observeAsState()` values don't survive `Don't keep activities`.

So my question is how can I let this survive configuration changes?

Comment: After some searching i found this in the Android docs:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state

I am a little confused though. Can't be the case that i have to implement this every time i want my app to survive process death??

Comment: What do you mean by "image is gone"? Does it mean that it takes some time until the image loads again or that it will never show again?

Comment: You are using AsyncImage, I am not sure from where, but you probably have to add some cache flag, or so... Your VM should be fine with pausing and resuming activities.